# How to access Xml child node value with by giveing child node name in condition In PHP using XMLREADER?

Tags: php, xmlreader

**I need to retrieve the value of the  node from my XML document, but only when the disposition attribute is equal to 'choicegroup'. Otherwise, I want to retrieve the value of the  node.**

"I have a large amount of XML data and I'm trying to decide whether to use XMLReader or SimpleXML. I've heard that SimpleXML can cause memory issues with very large XML documents, so I'm wondering if it's a good idea to use XMLReader. Are there any other suggestions for handling large XML documents?"

```
<infoObjects size="193">
<infoObject type="Publication" statusProcess="3" statusVisible="true" createdOn="2015-03-26T13:31:03.483+01:00" id="117482684" updatedOn="2021-03-19T11:08:48.783+01:00">
<attribute disposition="choicegroup" language="0" name="peerReviewed">
<data>20955</data>
<additionalInfo>Yes</additionalInfo>
</attribute>
<infoObject>

<infoObject type="Publication" statusProcess="3" statusVisible="true" createdOn="2014-04-04T09:22:56.766+02:00" id="113557224" updatedOn="2020-01-15T08:21:52.474+01:00">

<attribute disposition="choicegroup" language="0" name="complete author relations">
<data>18389</data>
<additionalInfo>Yes</additionalInfo>
</attribute>

</infoObject>
</infoObjects>
```

```
$infoObjects=array();
while ($xml->read()) {

            if ($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xml->name == 'infoObject') {

                $infoObject=array();
                $infoObject['id']=$xml->getAttribute('id');
                $infoObject['type']=$xml->getAttribute('type'); 
                $infoObject['statusVisible']=$xml->getAttribute('statusVisible'); 
                $infoObject['createdOn']=$xml->getAttribute('updatedOn');
                $infoObject['updatedOn']=$xml->getAttribute('updatedOn');

                // echo $xml->getAttribute('id');
                
            }
           
           

            if ($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xml->name == 'attribute') {
                // do something with the attribute element
                $nameAttribute = $xml->getAttribute('name');
                $languageAttribute=$xml->getAttribute('language');
                $dispositionAttribue=$xml->getAttribute('disposition');

                if ($languageAttribute==='1') {
                    
                    $nameAttribute=$nameAttribute."_en";

                }
                else{
                    $nameAttribute=$nameAttribute;
                }

                if ($dispositionAttribue==='choicegroup') {

                    // I want <additionalInfo>Yes</additionalInfo> value in the $attribute_value variable but its not working
                    $xml->read();
                    $attribute_value = $xml->readInnerXML();
                }
                else{
                    $xml->read();
                    
                    $attribute_value = $xml->readString();
                }

                $infoObject[strtolower($nameAttribute)]=$attribute_value;
                

                if ($nameAttribute=="publYear") {
                        $infoObjects[]=$infoObject;
                    }
                                
            }
             
        }

        $xml->close();
```

Comment: One approach I've come across before is to mix the use of XMLReader and SimpleXML.  ie if you've got a relatively shallow hierarchy with lots of repetition, then you can use XMLReader to work through the overall document (eg using `next()`), then convert small fragments of it into small SimpleXML documents for ease of accessing their content.